# Editing QTP imported Environmental variables

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables, qtp

Using QTP, I need to import environmental variables from an XML sheet, but there is a problem in editing them in run time, the imported Environmental variables are on read only mode, it cannot be edited.

I need to know if there is any way to ***import environment variables and edit them***
and i need to know, somehow, is there any method to create environment variables from ***code(programmatically)***

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to edit the values of the env variable which you are supplying first.

The concept behind supplying such value is that when you have paths or DSNs which remain constant ,then you supply these variables using external environment variables.

If you want to edit the values on runtime then you can use inputbox to pass a new value to the specified variable.

```
Environment.value("raj") = "lala"
asd = InputBox ("enter the value")
Environment.value("raj") = asd
MsgBox Environment.value("raj")
```

in this case it will show the next value supplied.